# AIR Chat on Android and AEC

Tags: android, air, aec

I am developing a chat application for Android, using AIR/Flex and Red5. But Acoustic Echo makes me stuck with headphones. With GTalk, we can enjoy handsfree chat. That means it is possible. I'm sure that I'm not first one to develop a chat app with AIR. What is the correct way for this project, to remove Acoustic Echo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AEC is not supported in the latest AIR runtime (3.1) for tablets.
Thus, there is no way of enabling AEC on tablets with AIR.  For now..

Comment: There must be a way, easy or hard. I have one idea, it may be silly, but no one answered to [that question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8208304/add-virtual-device-to-android) yet. Plus, does anyone have any idea if AEC will be supported on Android by AIR?

Comment: Yeah like I said there is none. I believe AEC will come to AIR rather sooner than later. But for now there is no solution.
Except for maybe writing a very complex Native Extension, which will probably never meet the correct performance requirements.